# Firebase Cloud Function isnt work in Prod. Getting error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am getting the following error when going to the URL.

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

I can not seem to figure out why. What did I do wrong?

Here is my `index.js` file.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var request = require('request');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const itemDescription = req.query.itemDescription;
  const pageNumber = req.query.pageNumber;
  const categoryId = req.query.categoryId;
  const sortBy = req.query.sortBy;
  const narrowSearch = req.query.narrowSearch;
  const typeOfListing = req.query.typeOfListing;
  const sellerExclusions = req.query.sellerExclusions;
  const tagsExclusions = req.query.tagsExclusions;
  const country = req.query.country;
  const minPrice = req.query.minPrice;
  const maxPrice = req.query.maxPrice;
  const entriesPerPage = req.query.entriesPerPage;
  const buyingFormat = req.query.buyingFormat;

  let operationName = "";
  let entriesPerPage2 = "";
  let sortOrder = "";
  let currentPage = "";

  if (pageNumber !== null) {
    currentPage = pageNumber;
  } else {
    currentPage = 1;
  }

  if (typeOfListing === 'active') {
    operationName = "findItemsAdvanced";
    entriesPerPage2 = 50;
  } else {
    operationName = "findCompletedItems";
    if (buyingFormat === "Auction") {
      entriesPerPage2 = 50;
    } else {
      entriesPerPage2 = 25;
    }
  }


  let apicall = "https://URL?";



  if (typeOfListing === "active") {
    if (sortBy !== null) {
       apicall += "&sortOrder=";
       apicall += sortBy;
       sortOrder = sortBy;
    } else {
      apicall += "&sortOrder=";
      apicall += "BestMatch";
      sortOrder = "BestMatch";
    }
  } else {
    if (sortBy !== null) {
       apicall += "&sortOrder=";
       apicall += sortBy;
       sortOrder = sortBy;
    } else {
      apicall += "&sortOrder=";
      apicall += "EndTimeSoonest";
      sortOrder = "EndTimeSoonest";
    }
  }


  if (categoryId !== null) {
    apicall += "&categoryId=";
    apicall += categoryId;
  }



  apicall += "&paginationInput.pageNumber=";
  apicall += currentPage;
  apicall += "&keywords=";
  apicall += itemDescription;
  apicall += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=" + entriesPerPage2;
  apicall += "&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value(0)=true";
 

  request(apicall, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          //here put what you want to do with the request

          let paginationOutput = JSON.parse(body).findCompletedItemsResponse[0].paginationOutput;
          let pageNumber = null;
          let totalPages = null;
          let totalEntries = null;
          let totalInPage = null;
          for (i = 0; i < paginationOutput.length; i++) {
            pageNumber = paginationOutput[i].pageNumber[0];
            totalPages = paginationOutput[i].totalPages[0];
            totalEntries = paginationOutput[i].totalEntries[0];
            totalInPage = paginationOutput[i].entriesPerPage[0];
          }

          let items = JSON.parse(body).findCompletedItemsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item;
          let itemId = null;
          let title = null;
          let categoryId = null;
          let categoryName = null;
          let galleryURL = null;
          let link = null;
          let dateEnded = null;
          let watchCount = null;
          let bestOfferEnabled = null;
          let listingType = null;
          let soldForOriginal = null;
          let timeLeft = null;
          let dateLeft = null;
          let bidCount = null;
          let shipping = null;
          //TODO

          let soldForBestOffer = null;
          var itemArray = {
              result: []
          };


          for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            itemId = items[i].itemId[0];
            title = items[i].title[0];
            galleryURL = items[i].galleryURL[0];
            link = items[i].viewItemURL[0];

            category = items[i].primaryCategory;
            for (j = 0; j < category.length; j++) {
              categoryName = category[j].categoryName[0];
              categoryId = category[j].categoryId[0];
            }

            listingInfo = items[i].listingInfo;
            for (k = 0; k < listingInfo.length; k++) {
              watchCount = listingInfo[k].watchCount === undefined ? "0" : listingInfo[k].watchCount[0];
              bestOfferEnabled = listingInfo[k].bestOfferEnabled[0];
              listingType = listingInfo[k].listingType[0];
              dateLeft = listingInfo[k].endTime[0];
            }

            sellingStatus = items[i].sellingStatus;
            for (jj = 0; jj < sellingStatus.length; jj++) {
              soldForOriginal = sellingStatus[jj].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__;
              bidCount = sellingStatus[jj].bidCount === undefined ? "0" : sellingStatus[jj].bidCount[0];
              timeLeft = sellingStatus[jj].timeLeft === undefined ? "-" : sellingStatus[jj].timeLeft[0];
            }

            shippingInfo = items[i].shippingInfo;
            for (ii = 0; ii < shippingInfo.length; ii++) {
              shipping = shippingInfo[ii].shippingServiceCost === undefined ? "0.0" : shippingInfo[ii].shippingServiceCost[0];
              shippingType = shippingInfo[ii].shippingType[0];
              if (shipping === "0.0") {
                shipping = "0.00"
              }
              if (shippingType === 'Calculated') {
                shipping = "TBD";
              } else {
                if (shipping === '0.00') {
                  shipping = "FREE";
                }
              }
            }

            itemArray.result.push({
                "itemId": itemId,
                "title": title,
                "galleryURL": galleryURL,
                "link": link,
                "categoryName": categoryName,
                "categoryId": categoryId,
                "bidCount": bidCount,
                "dateEnded": dateLeft,
                "watchCount": watchCount,
                "bestOfferEnabled": bestOfferEnabled,
                "listingType": listingType,
                "timeLeft": timeLeft,
                "soldForOriginal": soldForOriginal

            });
          }

          res.json({
            ack: "success",
            message: "results found",
            currentPage: pageNumber,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            totalEntries: totalEntries,
            totalInPage: totalInPage,
            results: itemArray.result,
            searchResult: JSON.parse(body).findCompletedItemsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item
          });
      } else {

        res.json({
          error: "didnt work"
        });
      }
  })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cloud Functions you need to manage asynchronous method calls via Promises. `request` supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a promise.

You should use another library, like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), along the following lines:

```
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {

        // ...
        let apicall = "https://URL?";

        // ...
        apicall += "&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value(0)=true";

        const response = await axios.get(apicall);

        // handle success
        // ...
        res.json({..});


    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ 'error': error });
    }
    
});
```

---

Note that you probably need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan.

As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title)

---

Also note that [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) is deprecated.

Comment: I will try it. I did sign up for blaze.

Comment: so I am not getting that error anymore, however, when I run the code through localhost, it works fine. When I deploy it, I get error, but it doesnt print the error.